# Fit a determinant inside a fraction

Tags: matrices, fractions

I want to put a determinant into a fraction, so it displays 1/matrix, (the reverse)

I have the determinant that is this one, but putting inside \frac does not do the trick.
What should I do instead?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\[
            \mathbf{|J|} =
            \begin{bmatrix}
            \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & 
                \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}  \\[1ex] 
            \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & 
                \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \\[1ex]
            \end{bmatrix}
            \]

\end{document}
```

Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't an exponent –1 be better?

Comment: What doesn't work with `\frac{1}{\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\[1ex] c & d \end{bmatrix}}`?

Comment: By the way, the correct semantics would be `|\mathbf{J}|` or, even better, `\lvert\mathbf{J}\rvert`. But how can a determinant be 1/matrix?